# I am having difficulties with apache after varnish installation

Tags: apache-2.2, varnish

I am running since few years directadmin on centos, now I need a better server environment for our sites. I installed last centos version on a rackspace instance, installation of directamin with all necessary services went well. Since I run a magento based store I wanted to test varnish, found everything that I need and installed varnish successfully. Te problem appears as soon as I switch varnish to port 80 and apache to 8080, report from apache error log:

```
[Wed Sep 18 06:50:25 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/htdocs/404.shtml 

[Wed Sep 18 08:56:58 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/htdocs/favicon.ico

[Wed Sep 18 08:56:58 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/htdocs/404.shtml
[Wed Sep 18 08:56:58 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/htdocs/404.shtml

[Wed Sep 18 09:09:58 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/htdocs/www.google.com

[Wed Sep 18 09:09:58 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/htdocs/404.shtml

[Wed Sep 18 09:09:58 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/htdocs/405.shtml

[Wed Sep 18 10:18:30 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/htdocs/robots.txt

[Wed Sep 18 10:18:30 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/htdocs/404.shtml

[Wed Sep 18 10:18:30 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/htdocs/skin

[Wed Sep 18 10:18:30 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/htdocs/404.shtml
```

The server doesn't use /var/www/htdocs at all, however there is a record in my httpd.conf:

```
DocumentRoot "DocumentRoot "/var/www/htdocs""
```

But the same config is on my old server as well and I didn't ever notice anything wrong.
As soon I switch back to apache only everything works fine with the same directive in apache config. New server has only one IP address and I run virtual hosts (configured in directadmin) same as on old server.
I am wondering what is wrong here, when I look into Varnish log the URLS for static content are ok, but in need of dynamic content apache is trying to look into /var/www/htdocs and there is nothing of use (empty dir), my files are in /home/user/public_html.
I can't figure out :(

Answer (score 0):

There are two places you need to change the port. In ports.conf you need:

```
NameVirtualHost *:8080
Listen 8080
```

and in the files for the Virtual Hosts in sites-enabled, so that they start:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
```

I suspect you forgot to change one of them.

Comment: yes the first one is inside the httpd.conf the secound one concerns virtual hosts, I tried already but no changes. If I try to open http://mydomain.com:8080/~user/index.php it takes ages and doesn't load css files at the end :(

Comment: Can you try: "wget --header="Host: mydomain.com" http://localhost:8080/" from the server. Just to see if it returns the correct files for mydomain.com (replace that with whatever your actual domain is).

Answer (score 0):

Do not change apache port, leave varnish on the port 8080 and redirect requests to the port 8080 on the firewall.

Comment: how will sending traffic another way around solve this problem?

Comment: This is global recommendation, regarding "File does not exist" - don't think this is related to ports somehow. I guess, you are using virtualhosts and "/var/www/htdocs/" is accessed when someone tries to contact your server without specifying host. Even localhost.